# Getting the array length from one form class to another form class c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string, forms, runtime-error

I initially declare an empty public string array in my program(form1) and when a button is clicked strings in a datagridview cell is put into the array! But I find a difficulty in getting the length of that array to another form class(form2)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
     public string[] strarray; 
     public string order;

     public Form1()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         var new1=dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value; 
         ordernew = new1.ToString();
         strarray = ordernew.Split(',');
         Form2 f2 = new Form2();        
         f2.Show();
     }
}
```

The assigning string values to the array using split function is successful! 
In form2 code is as follows!

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
     public Form2()
     {
          InitializeComponent();
     }

     private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          Form1 f1 = new Form1();
          for (int m = 0; m < f1.strarray.Length; m++)
          {
               label.Text="Hello";
          }                
     }
}
```

But when I run the program I get the error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at the for loop of form2 ! How can I correct this?

Comment: You are creating new instance of Form1 in Form2_Load. That instance is different than the one from which you are opening Form2. That's  why you are getting this exception. You need to send the Form1's current  instance  or the array itself to Form2 while opening it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are initializing again the `Form1`.

What you can do is add another property for Form2 then assigned a value it when calling `Form2`.

**In Form2:**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string[] strarray { get; set; } //add this.

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //You can also use foreach to avoid out of bound index
        foreach(var strItem in strarray)
        {
            label.Text = "Hello " + strItem;
        }
    }
}
```

**Then when you call it in `Form1`**

```
public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var new1=dataGridView2.Rows[0].Cells[2].Value; 
    order = new1.ToString();

    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.strarry = ordernew.Split(','); //surprise!! I don't know where you get ordernew variable but anyways, assign your values HERE...
    f2.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
```

This is what's causing the problem. you're creating a new window not using the old one, therefore the new window still doesn't have a strarr, the easiest way to solve this with minimal changes is to make Form2 construct takes a Form1 parameter and saves it in a field then use it.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private Form1 _form;
    public Form2(Form1 form)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _form = form;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int m = 0; m < _form.strarray.Length; m++)
        {
           label.Text="Hello";
        }

    }
}
```

And in the event handler of Form1 you'll pass `this` as parameter:

```
Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
f2.Show();
```

P.S: that's just one way with minimal changes, I don't encourage using it much as it can get confusing on larger scales.

Comment: thanx but at  _form = form; i get an error "The name form does not exist in the current context"!